# How to read a JSON file in Azure Databricks from Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: python, json, azure, databricks

I am using Azure Data Lake Store for storing simple JSON files with the following JSON:

```
{
  "email": "Usersemail@domain.com",
  "id": "823956724385"
}
```

The json files name is `myJson1.json`. The Azure Data Lake Store is mounted successfully to Azure Databricks.

I am able to load successfully the JSON file via

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(fi.path)
```

`fi.path` is a `FileInfo` Object which is the `MyJson1.json` file from above.

When i do

```
spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(fi.path)
df.show()`
```

i get the JSON object printed out correctly (DataFrame) as

```
+---------------------+------------+
|                email|          id|
+---------------------+------------+
|Usersemail@domain.com|823956724385|
+---------------------+------------+
```

What i want to do is, to load the JSON file with `json.load(filename)`, to be able to work with the JSON object within Python.

When i do

```
with open('adl://.../myJson1.json', 'r') as file:
  jsonObject0 = json.load(file)
```

then i get the following error

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory 'adl://.../myJson1.json'

When i try (the mount point is correct, i can list the file and also with spark.read into a DataFrame)

```
    jsonObject = json.load("/mnt/adls/data/myJson1.json")
```

then i get the following error

> 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

I have no idea what to do else to get the JSON loaded. My goal is to read the JSON object and iterate through the keys and their values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick was to use the following syntax for the file url

```
/dbfs/mnt/adls/data/myJson1.json
```

i had to add  `/dbfs/...` respectively replace `dbfs:/` with `/dbfs/` at the beginning of the url.

Then i could use

```
    with open('/dbfs/mnt/adls/ingress/marketo/update/leads/leads-json1.json', 'r') as f:
      data = f.read()

    jsonObject = json.loads(data)
```

Maybe it possible easier? But this works for now.

Comment: Yes, it's similar to the problems I had - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628005/write-the-results-of-the-google-api-to-a-data-lake-with-databricks. It is mentioned inthe help text but it cost me a lot of time! - https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html  "When you’re using Spark APIs, you reference files with "/mnt/training/file.csv" or "dbfs:/mnt/training/file.csv". If you’re using local file APIs, you must provide the path under /dbfs, for example: "/dbfs/mnt/training/file.csv". You cannot use a path under dbfs when using Spark APIs."

Answer (score 0):

To keep the JSON style and work specifically with the JSON formatted data you can try loading the data in with the following code:

```
   df = json.loads(dbutils.fs.head(fi.path))
```

To check the count of key value pairs:

```
   print(len(df))
```

Then to loop through the key:values:

```
for obj in df:
  email = df['email']
  print(email)
```

Hope this helps.